# Why do I have to toggle my Windows 10 Media Streaming PC's WiFi for the PS4 Media Player to detect it?

Tags: ps4, windows-10

I've set up the built-in DLNA media streaming server in Windows 10 and I've managed to get it working with the PS4, but I've noticed that whenever I open the Media Player app on the PS4, there is no server shown. Toggling the WiFi on the PC (which is always on, by the way) makes the PS4 detect it instantly. If I don't do this, it may take up to 2-3.. maybe even 5 minutes for the device to show up. Is there any way to speed up either the PS4's polling rate or Windows 10's rate of broadcasting the server availability?

I'm not sure if this problem is specific to the PS4 or a general Windows 10 thing. I tried the Local Network option in VLC on my Android phone and it was able to quickly detect my PC (however, it stayed on the loading screen after tapping on it and never finished).